# UIButton shadow not looking right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to add a shadow to a UIButton layer, but for some reason it cuts off at the bounds of the button. I set clipsToBounds is turned off, so I'm not sure why it's looking like this:

[image]

It's square, just like that, even though the shadow should not be squared..it should be soft and fading.

```
button.clipsToBounds = NO;
button.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
button.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:button.layer.bounds].CGPath;
button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
button.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
```

Am I missing anything?

Oh, and my button is a subclass of UIButton. I'm not sure if that makes a difference..
-Even with a shadowRadius of 0.0, I get a fully visible black square as my shadow

Comment: the code you pasted seems working ok on 5.1 see: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/36/zrzutekranu20120515o170.png/ So the problem might be somewhere else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clipsToBounds` will allow any child views to be drawn outside the bounds of your button.

Looks like it doesn't apply to your layer though :(

You might just have to make your button a bit bigger (or your shadow smaller!)

Comment: That's not an option in my case.I just really need it to work at its current size. My button is a subclass of UIButton..does that make a differnece?

Comment: nope, no difference at all! Another solution would be to add another UIView underneath your button containing an image of the shadow?

Comment: But there has to be a legit reason this is not working right? I'm doing something wrong here..this is odd behavior.

Comment: Ok wow I had a self.clipsToBounds = YES in my drawRect method.. I don't know what it was doing there

Comment: Ah, I had assumed that layer effects were trimmed by the layer bounds. Obviously they're not - I learn something new every day :)